# SQL finding members who are not friends of another member

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to find a query which will return members who aren't friends of a certain member. Here is the layout of my tables:

member_login:

```
MemberID, email, password
```

member_info:

```
memberID, first_name, last_name
```

member_friends:

```
friendID, req_member, req_date, app_member, app_date, date_deactivated
```

I tried to use NOT IN to run a query that would return the opposite of friends but nothing I try seems to be working.  Here's what I thought would work:

```
SELECT Mi.First_Name, Mi.Last_Name
  FROM Member_Info Mi
 WHERE Mi.Memberid NOT IN(
                           SELECT Mi.Memberid, Mi.First_Name, Mi.Last_Name
                             FROM Member_Info Mi, Member_Login Ml, Member_Friends Mf
                            WHERE Mi.Memberid = Ml.Memberid
                               AND (Mi.Memberid = Mf.Req_Member
                                   AND Mf.App_Member = 1
                                   OR Mi.Memberid = Mf.App_Member
                                   AND Mf.Req_Member =1)
                               AND Ml.Date_Deactivated <= 0
                               AND Mf.App_Date > 0
                          );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the query not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you try

```
SELECT Mi.First_Name, Mi.Last_Name
  FROM Member_Info Mi
 WHERE Mi.Memberid NOT IN(
                           SELECT Mi.Memberid
                              FROM Member_Info Mi, Member_Login Ml, Member_Friends 
                            WHERE Mi.Memberid = Ml.Memberid
                               AND (Mi.Memberid = Mf.Req_Member
                                   AND Mf.App_Member = 1
                                   OR Mi.Memberid = Mf.App_Member
                                   AND Mf.Req_Member =1)
                               AND Ml.Date_Deactivated <= 0
                               AND Mf.App_Date > 0
                          );
```

because you are returning three values in your NOT IN ( ... ) when it should be one

```
SELECT Mi.Memberid, Mi.First_Name, Mi.Last_Name
```

should be

```
SELECT Mi.Memberid
```

you might get another error about your FROM statement as you will need to join to tables together to compare values but your friend table does not have any matching values so this could be a problem (poor design)

**EDIT: database designs**

A lot of this comes down to experience really but there are a few good books which you can check out like [Head First SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526849) and [Relational Database Design Clearly Explained (The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Data Management Systems) (Paperback)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558608206), these are great books to learn the basics and basic design, i recommend you check them out

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much.

Sadly the table design is coming from the course I'm taking, material outdated? Any suggested reading for table design?

Answer (score 1):

@Thedirktastik, please check the correct use of `IN` clause. Here in [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174128%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can take a look.

In you `WHERE` clause you are using IN so the subquery returning the values should return only `Mi.Memberid` column values. And your query is returning several different columns. Should be something like:

```
....
WHERE Mi.Memberid NOT IN(
                           SELECT Mi.Memberid
                             FROM....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad design, and probably the reason for the down votes.  I would look into making the member_friends table an [intersect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) table (junction table).  It will make your design, and therefore queries, much easier to use and understand.